# Sound sometimes remains silent when playing more sounds in a row, why?

Tags: android, audio, button, media-player

I encountered with a weird problem and hope that someone can answer it.. I have 4x4 buttons, each of them plays a short 1 second sound if I click on it. My code for it:

```
Button_1= (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
            Button_1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    if (sound!=null){
                        sound.stop();
                        sound.release();
                        sound=null;
                    }
                    sound = MediaPlayer.create(Main.this, R.raw.short_sound);
                    sound.start();
                }
            });
```

So what happens is that I touch all the buttons in row, so firstly the button1, then button 2 and every time I touch it, a short sound gets played. But sometimes when I reach the 14th or 15th or 16th button it doesnt play the sound it should. The other buttons work but somehow the last 1,2 or 3 sometimes doesnt play any sound. If I start touching the buttons backwards, so I touch the 16th button first it always works, but then maybe the 1st and 2nd button remain silent.

What might cause this? LogCat does not write anything.

Answer (score 0):

When you call MediaPlayer.create() you allocate resources that aren't necessarily released by the GC mechanism.  You should manually release the MediaPlayer.release() routine. when you are finished with the object